# Methods on XElement base classes do not appear in derived classes

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

XElement implements IXmlLineInfo through a series of base classes so I can call LineNumber on the object, however intellisense does not see this property and I'm forced to cast the object to IXmlLineInfo.

```
IXmlLineInfo lineNumber = xelement;
var myLineNumber = lineNumber.LineNumber
```

All of which works, but shouldn't LineNumber appear on XElement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because [`XObject.IXmlLineInfo.LineNumber`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538457%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) declared as an [explicit interface member implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) :

```
int IXmlLineInfo.LineNumber { get; }
```

> An explicit interface member implementation is a method, property, event, or indexer declaration that references a fully qualified interface member name.
>
> .....
>
> An explicit interface member implementation can only be accessed through an interface instance, and is in that case referenced simply by its member name.
>
> [[MSDN: 13.4.1 Explicit interface member implementations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)]